# Server Side Rendering In React Native

Tags: react-native

I have been searching for examples of SSR in React Native but got the examples of how to implement Server side rendering in React only. Any resource would be of great help..!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using react-native-web? If yes, you can use NextJS (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-react-native-web), there is an example on how to use it with react-native. For native apps, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Not react-native-web, I guess instagram and facebook is using SSR in react native? There might be a way to do so.

Comment: @RahulSyal by any chance you found any?